# Como analisar o ditado «dias de muito, vésperas de nada»?

Tags: significado, ditados

Ao que parece existe também a variante «dias de muito, vésperas de pouco». Eu compreendo o ditado mais pelo contexto em que o ouvi do que pela análise do texto. É um crítica a quem gasta em excesso num dia, ficando sem nada para o dia seguintes. Só que para mim este moral seria melhor expresso por *vésperas de muito, dias de nada*, em que o *nada* do dia é apresentado como consequência dos excessos da véspera.

[Aqui no dicionárioinformal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/dia+de+muito+v%E9spera+de+pouco/) alguém que aparentemente partilha dos meus sentimentos deu engenhosamente a volta à coisa:

> É quando uma pessoa recebe salário, ou algum dinheiro e gasta todo com os amigos e familiares e não lembra do dia seguinte, tudo porque ontem tava durinho.

Ou seja, os excesso do dia resultam em dificuldades futuras, mas são eles mesmos resultado da escassez anterior. Não sei não, é engenho a mais para o meu gosto.

Uma coisa que me veio à cabeça é se *dia* poderá designar o período da manhã, e a *véspera* o da tarde. [Que *véspera* também tem este significado, tem](http://www.aulete.com.br/v%C3%A9spera) (daí os jornais vespertinos), e a sequência fica na ordem que eu prefiro. Mas não sei se dia alguma vez foi entendido só como o período da manhã.

Portanto o que quero saber é se *dia*, especialmente no contexto *dia e véspera*, pode ser, ou já foi, entendido como o período da manhã. Se não (ou mesmo se sim), qual é a interpretação literal do ditado?

Comment: Vendo-a assim isolada, eu não entenderia esta expressão como uma crítica a quem está a gastar tudo - mas como um aviso: "olha que hoje sobra-te, mas amanhã vai-te faltar..." Mas isso depende do contexto do uso, e eu nunca ouvi esta expressão em contexto.

Comment: @ANeves Eu lembro-me de ouvir o ditado sempre a jeito de comentário sobre a situação de alguém que andava a gastar em excesso ou já não tinha para gastar. Mas também pode muito bem servir para aconselhar, avisar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A interpretação literal do ditado é a seguinte:

Se num dado dia, suponhamos domingo (**véspera** de segunda-feira), gastarmos tudo o que temos (ou pelo menos grande parte do que temos), tal significa que, na segunda-feira, nada teremos (ou muito pouco teremos) para gastar.

Assim, os dias de muito gasto, são as vésperas de ficarmos com muito pouco ou sem nada para gastar.

Não obstante, esta expressão deverá ser tida em conta não no seu sentido literal mas no seu sentido metafórico, uma vez que pode ser utilizada a todo o nível temporal.

Por exemplo, se gastar tudo o que tenho em Janeiro (véspera de Fevereiro) então *dias de muito **em Janeiro**, são vésperas de pouco **em Fevereiro***.

Comment: Interessante. Não me tinha lembrado dessa interpretação. Tens alguma citação em que essa interpretação seja explícita e que possas incluir na resposta.

Comment: Não encontrei nenhuma citação, a minha explicação foi totalmente deduzida através da interpretação literal da expressão.

Por outro lado, este ditado encontra-se em desuso em Portugal, conforme [informação](http://cvc.cervantes.es/lengua/refranero/Ficha.aspx?Par=58512&Lng=6) do Instituto Cervantes.

Comment: Seria interessante encontrar. Esta interpretação é a que corresponde melhor ao sentido com que o ditado é usado. Mas formalmente, *dias de muito, vésperas (desses dias) de nada* é uma interpretação igualmente válida.

Answer (score 1):

Aprendi ouvindo minha mãe e tias, filhas de portugueses, que isto significava gastar ou consumir sem pensar nas consequências e no futuro.

Comment: Edson, bem-vindo ao site. Sim, é isso. Eu já explico isso na pergunta: "É um crítica a quem gasta em excesso num dia, ficando sem nada para o dia seguinte." A minha pergunta é um pouco diferente, é se *dia* (de muito) se refere à parte da manhã, e *véspera* (de nada) ao período seguinte. Uma outra interpretação, dada na resposta do aribeiro, é que o "dia de muito* é uma "véspera [de dias] de nada".